# not redirecting to HTTPS from HTTP

Tags: php, html, ssl, web, ssl-certificate

I had tried every method of redirection i.e `.htaccess` but none of the things work for me. as right now the `.htaccess` file contains

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.booksoncall.in/$1 [R=301,L]
```

it work fine on my computer and the http is redirecting successfully to https version, but http version is still accessable on other pc and is not redirecting to https same is happening on mobile devices.
website --- booksoncall.in

Comment: Where exactly did you place this .htaccess file, is it in the web root of the domain? Why are you checking for port 80, there are other more common ways to check if the request was made via HTTPS or not.

Comment: are htaccess files authorized by your apache config ?

Comment: Did you look at your logfiles?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try if you want *all* requests to be redirected to https

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} = example.com  [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} = www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

This should be done in the Vhost file for port 80

Comment: Your `RewriteCond` syntax is wrong (you do not use `=`). and also your setup will never work as multiple `RewriteCond` are parsed as AND together so the server name can not be both strings at the same time. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Thanks for your input @PatrickMevzek - I forgot the [OR] statement in my example. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

for short version.
you dont need the server name.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect all http request to https why not use

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80> 

    ServerName www.example.com:80

    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/

</VirtualHost>
```